# SAS Macro to create new variables with 64 prefixes

Tags: sas

I currently have data on 24 age groups stored like this:

```
Group   Estimate
agegp1  4.5
agegp2  5
agegp3 7.8
.
.
.
agegp24 9.5
```

I need to have these 24 age groups repeat 64 more times, each time having a unique prefix for 64 counties.  So it'll be something like:

```
NewGroup       Estimate
CountyAagegp1  4.5
CountyBagegp1  4.5
CountyCagegp1  4.5

CountyAagegp2 5
CountyBagegp2 5
CountyCagegp2 5
```

for all 24 groups and all 64 counties.

Is there a macro way in SAS to do such a thing iteratively?

Thanks!

Comment: In the future please include what you've attempted before posting a question and review the question guidelines on what to include in a post.

Comment: It's also worth noting, you're not creating variables here, you're adding values to your dataset. Adding variables would be adding new columns.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need a macro, just a regular old data step (or proc sql).

If you have a table like so:

```
data have;
  input Group $  Estimate;
datalines;
agegp1  4.5
agegp2  5
agegp3 7.8
;;;;
run;
```

And a county table like so:

```
data counties;
  input county $;
  datalines;
Cook
Lake
Dekalb
;;;;
run;
```

You just use a nested loop, using the `point` and `nobs` options, to iterate through the counties table, then output a row for each inner loop iteration.

```
data want;
  set have;
    do _n_ = 1 to nobs_counties;
      set counties nobs=nobs_counties point=_n_;
      output;
    end;
run;
```

You may want to do some work to concatenate county/age group variables, or just leave them separate.